# Delegate java.util.List#toArray(T[] a) in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I'm writing a Scala class that implements (wraps) a java.util.List, i.e.:

```
class MyList(backingList: java.util.List) extends java.util.List
```

The latter has a method toArray with a Java signature like this:

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

Naively, I wrote this as:

```
def toArray[T](a: Array[T]) = backingList toArray a
```

but the compiler complains that the call to toArray on backingList expects an `Array[? with java.lang.Object]`.

I think I've tried every possible variation over things like `Array[_ >: T with Object]` (which the compiler kindly suggests), but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you know such wrappers already exist in `JavaConversions`/`JavaConverters`? +1 BTW.

Comment: I know, but this is in the context of JavaFX's `ObservableList` (which extends java.util.List).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also works:

```
def toArray[T](a: Array[T with Object]) = backingList.toArray[T](a)
```

Comment: Indeed it does. `backingList toArray[T](a)` (i.e. without the dot) does not work though, but that is probably a Scala syntax thing.

Answer (score 2):

`Array[_ >: T with Object]` is syntactic sugar for `Array[X forSome {type X <: Object}]`, meaning an Array of objects whose type is a subtype of Object, but what you need is an Array of objects of the same type X, which is a subtype of Object. So in short, it is just a scoping issue.

```
def toarray(a: Array[X] forSome {type X <: Object}) = backingList toArray a
```

Comment: I don't think it overrides the `List.toArray` method.

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to, at least the question doesn't say that. Reading the question again, it might be interpreted that way. :D

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to implement `List.toArray`.